# creating folders on a network share in a asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

Ive created a app in asp.net using c# that needs to create folders on a number of network shares.  Ive configured the app pool account to use a domain account and given that domain account the correct permissions to the network share folder.  When i run my code im getting the following exception.  Any ideas?

```
Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
```

Comment: The system is telling you what's wrong: You've either supplied it with a user that doesn't exist, or you've used the wrong password for that user (if they exist). I recommend trying to connect to those network shares manually with the same credentials (copying/pasting them from the connection string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an account on the network that has the relevant access to that share and then set your application pool to use that identity.

This way, all requests from your application will appear to be that user.

Take care with this approach, however, as if anyone changes the password to that account, you will need to update it within your IIS

Answer (score 0):

OK seems I've been a bit of a chump. Seems there was some code I wrote (cant remember doing it) that impersonated the account I had set for the custom app pool but with the old password.  Simply commented out the code and it now works as expected.  Note to self!!!!!! Must read stack trace more carefully in future.

Apologies for wasting your time